# How can I check if the last 2 characters of a string are ,} and if yes remove the comma from it?

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm looking for a regex pattern which will filter a string.

If the last 2 characters are `,}` it should remove the `,` from the string.

Example:

```
helloworld,}
        //^
```

should become

```
hellworld}   
       //^
```

Comment: Have you tried something ? *looking for a regex pattern* We are not a regex generator here.

Comment: You don't even need regex for that. You could simply use `substr`.

Comment: substring wont work for what I know about substring, as the string is always different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on regex, you can use positive look ahead as

```
preg_replace('/,(?=}$)/', '', "helloworld,}")
// helloworld}
```

**Regex Explanation**

- `,` Matches `,`
- `(?=}$)` positive look ahead. Checks if the `,` is followed by `}` and then end of line `$`

Comment: With answering questions where no effort is shown you are encouraging the user in his behaviour.

Comment: @Rizier123 And I don't remember the last time I saw a question in regex tag with sincere effort from the user.

Comment: @Rizier123 I dont know anything about regex patterns, so that why I ask for help.

Comment: @user759235 Then you should have researched something and tried and posted a better question like.... *I tried like so and so and got so and so errors*

Comment: @nu11p01n73R You don't have to ask, if regex questions most of the times get answered, without haven OP do any work and with no explanations.

Comment: @Rizier123 And even the quality of questions are going down. Many of the questions are like normal google search solvable and users post them like that

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I know, I already took the paddles in my hands: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295501/3933332 , http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296383/3933332